# One ng-options usage - selecting one property instead whole object

Tags: angularjs

With a collection of objects, I need to have one property of the object shown in a selection list. My current HTML/AngularJS code is something like:

```
<select id="input-platform-id" class="form-control" ng-model="currentFactory.platform_id" data-ng-init="currentFactirt.platform_id" data-ng-options="p.id for p in platforms track by p.id">
</select>
```

The above loops over a collection of platform objects and it doesn't work for my need. I need to have the initial value is the same type as the property as well as the model.

I can think of a few approaches for this problem. I can change the back end code to have a collection of the property instead. That, however, requests many code changes due to our system has been built. On the AngularJS level, I could convert the platform objects to platform id objects. But, I don't know how to make a such conversion. Or, I could have the model as the same type of the platform and retrieve the id later. But, how to deal with the initial value which is not the same JSON object type as the platform?

The JSON is something like:

```
[
  {        
    "created_by": "joe",
    "created_date": "2015-08-22T05:22:48Z",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test Platform"
  }    
  {       
    "created_by": "jobs",
    "created_date": "2015-10-06T23:45:50Z",
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Test Platform 1"
  }
]
```

The AngularJS code:

```
  <select id="input-platform-id"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    data-ng-model="selectedPlatformID"
                                    data-ng-init="selectedPlatformID = platforms[0].id"
                                    data-ng-options="platform.id as platform.name for platform in platforms">
  </select>
```

And the generated HTML code starts with the following line

```
 <option value="?" selected="selected" label></option>
```

The rest value field starts from 0, 1, 2, ... in one increment sequence, which is not the data in the id field.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax to let you to have the best of both world.

```
<select id="input-platform-id" 
        class="form-control" 
        ng-model="currentFactory.platform_id" 
        data-ng-init="currentFactirt.platform_id = platforms[0].id" 
        data-ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in platforms track by p.id">
</select>
```

Note: If your `$scope.platforms` comes asynchronusly, consider init the `ng-model` in controller when you get the data.

---

Edit: include example

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.platforms = [{
    "created_by": "joe",
    "created_date": "2015-08-22T05:22:48Z",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test Platform"
  }, {
    "created_by": "jobs",
    "created_date": "2015-10-06T23:45:50Z",
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Test Platform 1"
  }]
  
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.selectedPlatformID = 23;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <select id="input-platform-id" 
          class="form-control" 
          data-ng-model="selectedPlatformID" 
          data-ng-options="platform.id as platform.name for platform in platforms">
  </select>
  <br>selectedPlatformID: {{selectedPlatformID}}
</div>
```

Comment: @lcycool Thanks for your quick response. I don't see a right generated HTML code though: <option value="?" selected="selected" label></option> and the model is the entire platform object, but not an ID property value after the data is saved in the controller.

Comment: @TeeKai included example.

Comment: @lcycool Thank very much for your detailed sample. After removing 'track by ..' in the ng-options, the selection works. The initial value comes with a valid data. So I change how the ng-model is initialized. All works as desired right now.

Comment: @cycool I just found a problem after removing the "track by ...". The value field on the first line is a correct via, zero. There isn't a zero value in the data. And there are two "selected".

Comment: @TeeKai I can't understand your case. Do you have duplicate id in your data? There isn't a zero id in my example as well.

Comment: @cycool There aren't  duplicated id, but the name field. I provide more details in my original answer.

Comment: @TeeKai Can you show the whole platforms object? Is it not an array?

Comment: The data is an array shown as the updated data. The code works right now although generated HTML code doesn't seem to be right: there are two selected items on the list of options. Also, I thought the value field in option tag should be platform.id, but a series of indexes started with 0.

Comment: @TeeKai Although you didn't mention it, but I think you are trying to set the initial value based on some value you get asynchronusly. I updated my example to demonstrate that.

Comment: That is correct. For my case, the model has a value prior to the page. And a selection from the dropdown list will override the data.